# wrapping a function in a class

Tags: python, oop

This is not really language-specific, but I'll use Python to explain my question.

My program has several nearly self-contained functions. The command line arguments select one of these functions, and provide the input file name. The function is then executed:

```
# main.py:
import functions
def main():
  filename = sys.argv[1]
  function_name = sys.argv[2]
  function = getattr(functions, function_name)
  result = function(filename)
  # do something with result

# function.py contains all the functions:
def function1(filename):
  # ...
```

I had a feeling that I should probably use classes rather than functions, so I wrapped each function in a class. But now each class looks pretty silly: it's only instantiated once, and all it does is execute its constructor, which does exactly what my old functions did. Then I can call a certain method to retrieve the return value:

```
# new version of main.py:
import classes
def main():
  filename = sys.argv[1]
  cls_name = sys.argv[2]
  cls = getattr(classes, cls_name)
  calculation = cls(filename)
  result = calculation.result()
  # do something with result

# classes.py:
import functions
class Class1:
  def __init__(self, filename):
    self.result = functions.function1(filename)
  def result(self):
    return self.result

# functions.py is unchanged
```

This doesn't seem to be any better than when I had functions. Is there a way to make my code object-oriented in a more useful way?

Comment: A function -- standing alone -- is an object.  Since a function object is an object, it's object-oriented.  What are you asking?  How to make a function object somehow *more* object-oriented?  It's already an object.  An instance of class `callable`.  What more do you want?

Comment: I was just thinking that maybe I shouldn't be having a bunch of global functions in my code. Somehow I thought it's better to have mostly classes at the global level.

Comment: "it's better to have mostly classes at the global level"?  Why?  What's "better" about it?  Define "better", please.  What is your objective?

Comment: Max - there is nothing wrong with module-level functions if they are really stateless -- they're not using globals or other kluges to save info between calls, or passing a lot of info around between them that would better be saved as instance attributes.

Comment: @S.Lott: not sure; I read it somewhere. The only reason I know of not to use global functions is namespace pollution, but in my case it's obviously not an issue.

Comment: @agf: suppose I do have information passed between them - but only in a single, linear execution path. Would it be enough of a reason to wrap them in a class like I did? My class would be instantiated just once, and its methods would always be called in a fixed order.

Comment: @max: "I read it somewhere"?  Can you provide a reference or a link?  It's not a very sensible thing.  Java -- of course -- is forced to wrap functions as classes because of weird limitations in the Java compiler.  But Python (and some other languages) don't have this limitation.  I'd like to know what your objective is, what your definition of "better" is and where you got these ideas.  Otherwise, it's not easy provide an "answer" to this question.

Comment: Just wrapping them in a class doesn't provide you any benefit, so there is no reason to do it. Only if it will actually simplify the code should you reorganize into user-defined classes (making useless wrapper classes makes it more complicated) -- and if you do that, actually refactor your code to use the features of classes, like instance attributes.

Comment: @Max - I don't see a problem with global functions, unless you think you're likely to copy/paste your source into some other program that might have a naming clash. But if you're looking to somehow group them can you put them all into the _same_ class, or nest them within a single top-level function? Then your `main()` could call the new top-level function and tell it which of its children to execute and return a result from.

Comment: @S.Lott: I thought it was an established principle, but I see now that it's not (perhaps I remembered it from another language). In fact, I found this: http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=377972, which is consistent with what you're saying. Should I remove my question? I now understand it's not well-posed.

Comment: @nnnnnn: you recommend the nesting to clean up the namespace?

Comment: I don't recommend it as such because I don't think it's necessary. I suggested it because you said that you _want_ to clean up the namespace. (I'm in the process of learning Python and have not got very far yet, so I don't know what the normal practice is. In JavaScript I would probably put all of the functions in question as "methods" of a single object.)

Comment: @nnnnnn: "I don't know what the normal practice is".  Clearly.  Folks don't gather random functions into a class to reduce namespace pollution.  They gather functions into a module, instead.  It's simpler.

Comment: @S.Lott - thanks, yeah, though it looked to me like the functions were already imported from a single module and for some reason Max wanted some way to group them further. But then the question started with "This is not really language-specific, but I'll use Python to explain my question", which is why I was happy to respond even though I've learned only a little Python, and why I mentioned what I'd do in JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you were writing Java or C# then you would implement these functions as static methods. In those languages all methods have to be part of a class due to the design of the language. In Python, whilst you can emulate a static method, there is absolutely no need to do so for this example.

Python's creator, Guido van Rossum, has [argued in favour of the use of functions rather than methods](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-November/004643.html).

> First of all, I chose len(x) over x.len() for HCI reasons (def
>   __len__() came much later). There are two intertwined reasons
>   actually, both HCI:
>
> (a) For some operations, prefix notation just reads better than
>   postfix — prefix (and infix!) operations have a long tradition in
>   mathematics which likes notations where the visuals help the
>   mathematician thinking about a problem. Compare the easy with which we
>   rewrite a formula like x*(a+b) into x*a + x*b to the clumsiness of
>   doing the same thing using a raw OO notation.
>
> (b) When I read code that says len(x) I know that it is asking for the
>   length of something. This tells me two things: the result is an
>   integer, and the argument is some kind of container. To the contrary,
>   when I read x.len(), I have to already know that x is some kind of
>   container implementing an interface or inheriting from a class that
>   has a standard len(). Witness the confusion we occasionally have when
>   a class that is not implementing a mapping has a get() or keys()
>   method, or something that isn’t a file has a write() method.
>
> Saying the same thing in another way, I see ‘len‘ as a built-in
>   operation. I’d hate to lose that. /…/

Whilst this is not directly related to your question it does challenge the sometimes dogmatic stance that methods are always to be preferred to functions.

In my opinion, in Python, using functions is a better solution than creating classes.

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the specific case you are modeling.  You want to associate a function (several functions!) with a string name, that gets passed in as `sys.argv[1]`.  In python, the most convenient way to make an association from strings is with a `dict`!  Your code might look a bit like this:

```
# main.py:
import functions
function_map = {
    'function1': functions.function1,
    'function2': functions.function2,
    'function3': functions.function3,
}
def main():
  filename = sys.argv[1]
  result = function_map[sys.argv[2]](filename)
  # do something with result

# function.py contains all the functions:
def function1(filename):
  # ...
```

Ok, so that's enough to get rid of the `getattr()`, but maybe there's a little more we can do.  Some of those functions probably have some code in common;  I'd bet that most of them try to open the file, although there may be some that don't.  Now we're getting closer to something that might be a use for classes!  You can still treat objects the same way as regular functions by defining a `__call__` method.

```
class OpenFileFunctor(object):
    def __init__(self, mode='rb'):
        self.mode = mode
    def __call__(self, filename):
        # do some stuff with self.foo and filename!
        return open(filename, self.mode).read()
```

Alternately, you might just not have very much to say in the function body.  You can use a lambda expression to shorten the function to just the entry in the dict.

```
# main.py:
import functions
import os
function_map = {
    'function1': functions.function1,
    'slurp_unviersal': functions.OpenFileFunctor('rU'),
    'is_text_file': (lambda fn: fn.lower().endswith(".txt") and os.path.isfile(fn)),
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with global functions in your code if that's all that is needed of them. When you have functions that require being in class, they are normally related to that class and then they are called methods. :) There's no need to add the complexity of nesting a function within a class. Not in Python, anyway.